# Storing Individual Quiz Answers in LearnPress Plugin - WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, lms, learnpress

I am working on an education website using *WordPress* and the *LearnPress plugin*. The site allows users to subscribe to courses and complete quizzes. While LearnPress provides overall quiz results, I need to implement a feature that stores individual answers for each user who submits a quiz.

This is my first time using LearnPress, and I'm not sure where to start. I've read online about the possibility of finding a "hooks" file in the site's File Manager, which could be used to achieve custom functionalities.

My goal is to generate a PDF or some other format to store individual quiz answers in a database, preferably associated with the user ID or name.

Could anyone provide guidance or point me in the right direction on how to approach this task within the LearnPress plugin? Any help, advice, or code snippets would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Ps: i've already buy the student gradebook add-ons, i'm not sure this can help.

My site is on plesk, i would like to know how to configure secure backup before writing code.
I just download the latest Backup...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.